# How to use pandas to get output in tabular format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the below mentioned code was all ok untill i tried to beautify it using pandas, can anyone pls suggest how can i wrap the output in tabular format with headers, borders?

old code :

```
import eikon as ek
ek.set_app_key('8854542454521546fgf4f4gfg5f4')
df, err = ek.get_data('ESCO.NS',['TR.DivUnadjustedGross','TR.DivExDate','TR.DivType'],{'SDate': '2020-07-01','EDate': '2021-07-26','DivType': '61:70'})

print(df)
```

New code :

```
import eikon as ek
import pandas as pd
ek.set_app_key('8854542454521546fgf4f4gfg5f4')
df = pd.dataframe(ek.get_data('ESCO.NS',['TR.DivUnadjustedGross','TR.DivExDate','TR.DivType'],{'SDate': '2020-07-01','EDate': '2021-07-26','DivType': '61:70'}))

print(df, headers='Keys',tablefmt='psql')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this call `ek.get_data` is returning two things, you can add a line like this:

```
import eikon as ek
ek.set_app_key('8854542454521546fgf4f4gfg5f4')
data, err = ek.get_data('ESCO.NS',['TR.DivUnadjustedGross','TR.DivExDate','TR.DivType'],{'SDate': '2020-07-01','EDate': '2021-07-26','DivType': '61:70'})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe' getting this now

Comment: Switching to camel-case (pd.DataFrame()) cleans up the problem.